# Erro ao buscar informações do blogger via json

Tags: java, android, json

Eu estou tentando pegar informações do blogger via `json` e colocar para aparecer num `recyclerview`.
Porém não estou conseguindo. Sou iniciante na programação, então estou ileso se terá de assinar alguma `key` para que possa liberar o conteúdo por `json`.

Edit: Os dados não estão sendo exibidos.

Edit 2: Parece que descobrir qual é o problema, mas ainda não consigo soluciona-lo.
Acontece que o que eu quero obter não é um JSONArray:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray version = response.optJSONArray("title");
```

E sim um JSONObject:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject getTitle = response.getJSONObject("title");
```

Até então o app persistia no Toast de falha, após essa mudança não aparece mais a mensagem.
Porém, nada na tela ainda é exibido.

Aparece isso quando estou monitorando o andamento do app:
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for title

Sendo que o "title" realmente é um objeto.

Código depois da mudança:

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
        Log.d("Debug", result);
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject getTitle = response.getJSONObject("title");
            rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < getTitle.length(); i++) {
                RowItem item = new RowItem();
                String put = getTitle.getString("$t");
                item.setTitle(put);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está o código java da minha aplicação.

RowItem:

```
public class RowItem {

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class IAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<RowItem> listItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public IAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listar_apps, null);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
        final RowItem listItem = listItems.get(i);

        customViewHolder.applyTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItem.getTitle()));

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(listItem);
            }
        };
        customViewHolder.applyTitle.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != listItems ?
        listItems.size() : 0);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView applyTitle;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.applyTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo_app);
        }
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

AtividadePrincipal:

```
public class Creator extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = "Creator";

    private List<RowItem> rowItems;
    private IAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_creator);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        String url = "http://techpositivo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";
        new GetData().execute(url);
    }

    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                //200 representa HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }

                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; //Sucesso
                } else {
                    result = 0; //Falhou
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //Falhou
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (result == 1) {
                adapter = new IAdapter(Creator.this, rowItems);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(RowItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(Creator.this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Creator.this, "Falhou...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray version = response.optJSONArray("title");
            rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < version.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject title = version.optJSONObject(i);
                RowItem item = new RowItem();
                item.setTitle(title.optString("$t"));
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Obs.: Não reparem no meu site na versão desktop, pois meu intuito é apenas para smartphones.

Comment: Ele não está exibindo? ocorre algum erro? Está com dificuldade em qual parte?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Sim. Os dados não estão sendo exibidos.

Comment: o que vem na sua variável **response**?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Reparando o meu código. O response carrega todo texto do json. Em seguida é passado para o método parseResult para fazer a distribuição.

Comment: Eu acho q o erro está na hora de pegar o valor no método **parseResult** tente colocar na primeira linha deste método o seguinte: **Lod.d ("Debug", result);** e veja se ele mostra no console o mesmo q vc vê acessando a url

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Sim, o Debug constou o mesmo conteúdo quando acessado pelo link. Mas parece que recebi um erro logo abaixo: D/Creator: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.lenght()' on a null object reference

Comment: **response.optJSONArray("title")** não existe ! Isto que o código quer dizer

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Acessando o link você pode me ajudar a identificar quais valores devo chamar para receber o nome de cada postagem, por exemplo? Estou tentando de tudo qualquer jeito, mas não tô conseguindo.

Comment: Claro! Não consigo agora, mas assim que possível posto a resposta

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Amigo. Muito obrigado pela disposição. Minha pergunta foi editada, creio que com melhorias (novidades). Veja lá, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre ao navegar nas propriedades do `JSON`

Neste caso, para termos o título dos post's é necessário navegar no seguintes Objetos:

**feed** > **entry** > **title**

No objeto title teremos a propriedade `$t`

Segue um exemplo:

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    private List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            //200 representa HTTP OK
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                parseResult(response.toString());
                result = 1; //Sucesso
            } else {
                result = 0; //Falhou
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result; //Falhou
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        for(final String title : titles){

            RowItem item = new RowItem();
            item.setTitle(title.optString("$t"));
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        adapter = new IAdapter(Creator.this, rowItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(RowItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(Creator.this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

            // Pegamos o feed
            JSONObject feed = new  JSONObject(response.get("feed").toString());
            // Pegamos o  entry
            JSONArray entry =  feed.getJSONArray("entry");
            for (int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {
                // Pegamos um item
                JSONObject post = entry.optJSONObject(i);
                // Pegamos o objeto title
                final JSONObject titleJson = new JSONObject(post.get("title").toString());
                //Pegamos o valor
                titles.add(titleJson.getString("$t"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Observação**:  Criei uma lista e adicionei os títulos, e apenas no `onPostExecute`, alteramos os elementos da tela!

**Sugestão**:  Ao invés de uma lista de `String` crie um objeto com todos as propriedades que veem na lista de **entry** !

Uma dica para descobrir quais são estas propriedades é o `Log.i()`

Comment: Certíssimo. Trabalhou tranquilamente. Muito obrigado. Mas agora que fui ver, meu site tem mais de 100 postagens, e nesse link (json) lista poucos títulos de apps(cerca de 25). Será que tem alguma forma de eu conseguir o nome de todos os posts?